# POST request to get access token from keycloak fails

Tags: r, rest, authentication, curl, keycloak

I am trying to get an access token from keycloak's REST-API:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

admin_user <- list(
  username = "admin",
  password = "admin",
  grant_type = "password",
  client_id = "admin_cli"
)
tkn01 <- POST(
  "https://www.example.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token",
  body = toJSON(admin_user),
  add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
)
```

This results in an error:

```r
rawToChar(tkn01$content)
[1] "{\"error\":\"invalid_request\",\"error_description\":\"Missing form parameter: grant_type\"}"
```

Although `grant_type` has been provided.

I also tried with `curl`:

```r
curl -i -X POST -d '{"username":"admin","password":"admin","grant_type":"password","client_id":"admin_cli"}' https://www.example.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.17.8
Date: Wed, 09 Dec 2020 16:27:14 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 84
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-store
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing form parameter: grant_type"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting JSON structure and that's wrong. You just need to post it as parameters/fields. Curl example:

```
curl -s -X POST \
  --data "scope=${SCOPE}" \
  --data-urlencode "client_id=${CLIENTID}" \
  --data-urlencode "client_secret=${CLIENTSECRET}" \
  --data-urlencode "username=${USERNAME}" \
  --data-urlencode "password=${PASSWORD}" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" \
  https://www.example.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an error `{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Invalid client credentials"}`. I tried this: `curl -s -X POST --data-urlencode "username=admin" --data-urlencode "client_id=admin_cli" --data-urlencode "password=admin" --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" https://www.example.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`. Do I need `scope` and `client_secret` in this case? Ultimately, I want to get an access_token and use it to create users via REST-API.

Comment: @eastclintw00d you need `client_secret` if used client (`admin_cli` in your case) is not a public client (usually default keycloak `admin-cli` client is public, but it looks like you are using different one `admin_cli`, so it is not clear if it is public or not). `scope is also required, at least `openid` scope.

Comment: Ok, I had a typo in it: `admin_cli` instead of `admin-cli`. This works: `curl -s -X POST --data-urlencode "username=admin" --data-urlencode "client_id=admin-cli" --data-urlencode "password=admin" --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" https://www.example.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`. Thanks again!